# Java Copying Data from Array Rather than Reference

Tags: java, arrays

In the following code, I am trying to duplicate the 2d array 'cur,' swapping two values in the array, and eventually add it to an arraylist I will be using later in the program.  My problem is, every time I switch these values in the array 'temp' (has the cloned values of 'cur') it also switches the values in the array 'cur.'  I'm confused because I have tried clone(), Arrays.copyof, even made a new constructor for the PuzzleNode class that takes the values from cur, yet every time 'cur' doesn't reset to its original value when the iteration of the loop finishes.  Any help is much appreciated.

Here's the code:

```
//generate the puzzles and swap the tiles
    for (int i = 0; i < possibleSwaps.size(); i++) {
        //stores the 2d array of Nodes
        PuzzleNode temp = new PuzzleNode();
        //instantiate the 2d array and populate it with values of cur
        temp.puzzle = new Node[cur.puzzle.length][cur.puzzle[0].length];
        for (int j = 0; j < cur.puzzle.length; j++) {
            temp.puzzle[j] = cur.puzzle[j].clone();
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < cur.puzzle.length; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < cur.puzzle[0].length; k++) {
                if (temp.puzzle[j][k].value == possibleSwaps.get(i).value) {
                    //switch the values, values should always be distinct
                    int prev = temp.puzzle[zeroNode.x][zeroNode.y].value;
                    temp.puzzle[zeroNode.x][zeroNode.y].value = possibleSwaps.get(i).value;
                    temp.puzzle[possibleSwaps.get(i).x][possibleSwaps.get(i).y].value = prev;
                }
            }
        }
        //prints out the 2d array that should be the same everytime.  But isn't
        printPuzzle(cur.puzzle);
    }
```

Example of Print Out:

(Original 2d array I want to always have)

```
1   2   3   
4   6   8   
7   []  5
```

(Switched the [] and the 6, I NEED the [] to remain where it originally was in the previous iteration, so it can be swapped with the 5 and 7 in the next iterations)

```
1   2   3   
4   []  8   
7   6   5
```

(Stays where it was swapped in the previous iteration)

```
1   2   3   
4   []  8   
7   5   6   

1   2   3   
4   []  8   
5   7   6
```

Comment: Try System.arraycopy(),it's more effective way to do this.

Comment: It sounds like you need to copy the Node objects themselves.

Comment: Can you write a more compact code so that we can reproduce the problem on our own machines?

Comment: @LouisWasserman you got me on the write track.  The Node objects weren't being cloned correctly in the clone() so I implemented cloneable and sure enough it worked.  Thank you sir, now I may get a few more hours of sleep tonight.